# Adding vtype to column in grid EXT-JS

Tags: javascript, regex, extjs, grid, numeric

I have a grid that has a column in which the user can enter only a positive integer. Every other value is unacceptable.

For a text field i could have handled a similar scenario using a VType, but i am not able to add a VType to a column of a grid. Is it even possible to add one?

If yes, it would be great if someone could show me how to do it.

PFB the code for the grid:

```
xtype:'gridpanel',
id:'my-grid',
overflowY:'auto',
sortableColumns:false,
enableColumnHide:false,
enableColumnResize:true,
plugins:[
    Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
        clicksToEdit:1,
        pluginId:'cellEditing'
    })
],
store:new Ext.data.Store({
    fields:['data1', 'data2'],
    addRecords:false,
    data:storeData
}),
columns:[
    {
        text:'NumberColumn',
        dataIndex:'data1',
        menuDisabled:true,
        sortable:false,
        flex: 4,
        editor:{
            xtype:'textfield',
            allowBlank:false,
            //tried adding vtype here...but didn't work...
        },
        renderer:function (value, metaData, record) {
            return value
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A vtype can be applied to a field never a column. A column only visualize a value while a fields allows you to enter and manipulate it. In your case you are using Cellediting which overlays the column with a Ext.form.Field instance, in your case a textfield which then allows you to enter/manipulate a value. So adding a valid vtype to a fieldconfig should work. Anyway there is no vtype for numeric so using it here is worthless in your case.

But your problem can easily be solved by using the following field:

```
{
    xtype: 'numberfield',
    allowDecimals: false,
    minValue: 0,
    allowBlank: false
}
```